# how to create "href" using JavaScript of a google drive file

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have a dynamic table created using JavaScript my dataArray consist of many information including drive file downloadable link example :-

`dataArray[i][4]` has google file dowanload link = `drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1YH6xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxphUl`

Now I can't create a downloadable link using the url field of my dataset I tried following:-

```
function getreferData(dataArray)

{
                   var ray = dataArray.splice(0,1)
                   let table = document.getElementById('thead1');
                   var tableHeaderRow = document.createElement("tr");
                   table.appendChild(tableHeaderRow);
                   for(i=0;i<ray[0].length;i++){
                   var tableHeader = document.createElement("th");
                   tableHeaderRow.appendChild(tableHeader);
                   tableHeader.innerHTML = ray[0][i];
                   }
                   let tbody = document.getElementById('perf');
                   for (var i=0;i<dataArray.length;i++)
                   {
                  
                   let row = document.createElement("tr")
                    
                    for (var j=0;j<dataArray[i].length;j++)
                       {
                       if (j==4)
                         {
                         let col = document.createElement("td")
                         var a = document.createElement("a");
                             a.href = "/'"+dataArray[i][j]+"/'";
                         var node = document.createTextNode("Click here")
                         a.appendChild(node)
                         col.appendChild(a)
                         row.appendChild(col)
                         }
                       else
                         {
                         let col = document.createElement("td")
                         col.innerText = dataArray[i][j]
                         row.appendChild(col)
                         }
                       }
                   
                   tbody.appendChild(row); 
                   }
```

image of my array logs:-

[image]

Comment: Try to remove wrapping `\ ` from `\"+dataArray[i][j]+"` to `dataArray[i][j]`

Comment: I tried that way earlier but it did not work.

Comment: Would you mind sharing a snapshot of `dataArray`? This would help to debug by running above in a snippet code

Comment: I have added the snapshot of my dataArray in my question please check

Comment: It worked when I used "https://" in the link. Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: @Mask Post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it worked by Adding `"https://"` in my link `drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1YH6xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxphUl`.